# Android memory management

Tags: android, memory, loading, lazy-evaluation

I am working on an Android app, that has lots of images (a few hundred) to be displayed in a grid format. I am using a custom HorizontalListView and a couple of LazyLoading, Caching techniques to achieve the required UI.

What I have noticed (in DDMS) is, the app consumes a lot more memory on Android 3.2 compared to Android 2.3.3 I was expecting a small difference, however my app consumes about 35Mb on Android 3.2 and only 12Mb on 2.3.3. Any particular reason for such a huge difference?

Answer (score 1):

Are you considering [supporting multiple screens](http://anidea.com/technology/designer%E2%80%99s-guide-to-supporting-multiple-android-device-screens/) while loading images?

I think your problem is screen type and the size of image. If you focus on this area, you may get improved results.

Comment: Actually I am not worried too much about the way they are rendered on the screen (as mentioned in the link you have given). Since both the devices are 10' tablets the image sizes remain same. What puzzles me the most is why would Android 3.2 eat up so much memory, like 3 times!